# Printing to file in for loop using Batch Script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to write to xml file using a batch script, however it only writes the last loop to the file. The variable `Project_Choice` is just two comma separated strings. It prints to the console correctly, however writes only the last loop in the `xml` file. Where am I going wrong?

```
for %%i in (%Project_choice%) do (                            
    echo(^<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?^>
    echo(^<testConfiguration^>
    echo(^<TestEvents^>
    echo(^<TestEvent^>%%i^</TestEvent^>
    echo(^</TestEvents^>
    echo(^</testConfiguration^>
)> C:\cijobscript\Test.xml
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`>` creates a new file. `>>` appends to an existing file. Change the `>` to `>>` BUT this will append the new data to any existing file, so you'd need to delete it first.

-- OR --

use

```
(for .... do (echo....))>filename
```

to create a new file

Note here the `for` command itself is within parentheses.

Comment: You won't notice it with that few `echo`s, but the second option is much much faster, especially if it generates a lot of data (because it has to open the file just once instead of opening, searching for the end of file, writing and closing the file for each and every line).